# How do you assign output of plt.hist() to a variable so that it can be plotted by calling variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot a histogram using the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = [0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4]
histogram = plt.hist(l, bins=5)
plt.show()
```

However, if I subsequently enter:

```
histogram
plt.show()
```

I get no plot, but no error either. "Histogram" returns the following as expected (as if I entered "plt.hist(l, bins=5)" as usual):

```
>>> (array([2., 3., 1., 2., 4.]), array([0. , 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3.2, 4. ]), <a list of 5 Patch objects>)
```

What is different about running plt.hist() when assigning to a variable as opposed to simply calling the variable? Is there a way to assign the output of plt.hist() to a variable such that I can plot from it after simply calling the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.hist([1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the retrieved variables are arrays on the y- and x-axes, you can get the values from that array and draw a graph. As an example, we have drawn a scatter plot with the acquired data. Does this fit the intent of your question?

```
for x,y in zip(histogram[1],histogram[0]):
    print(x,y)
    plt.scatter(x,y)

0.0 2.0
0.8 3.0
1.6 1.0
2.4000000000000004 2.0
3.2 4.0
```

[image]